# Reference request for cohomology and differential forms

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, differential-forms

I have been watching the [Algebraic topology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ap2c1dPyIVo&list=PL6763F57A61FE6FE8) lectures of Prof. Norman Wildberger. On finishing the series, I am eager to know whether there is any follow up lecture series on cohomology, differential forms etc.

Unfortuantely I couldn't find the lectures by Wildberger.  Are there any good set of lectures to understand the ideas of cohomology, differential forms etc.

NB: I have Algebraic topology book by Allen Hatcher, I find it has slightly different notation as used by the Wildberger in his lectures.

Comment: Notation is much less universal than one might ideally think it ought to be. Every author finds reasons to optimize the notation to their own purposes.

Comment: Differential forms are used in the theory of smooth manifolds and differential geometry. Algebraic topology, on the other hand, usually looks at much more general classes of spaces than smooth manifolds, so these are a priori pretty different things (though there's a lot of connection). Could you be more precise about what exactly you are interested in/looking for ? E.g. when you say "cohomology", do you mean de Rham or singular cohomology? Note there's a classic book called "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology" by Bott & Tu, but I can't tell whether it would be what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, I want to learn de Rham Cohomology, characteristic classes, hopf fibration etc.